# How to find the inverse of this $3 \times 3$ block matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

> Given $$E = \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{bmatrix}$$ define the following block matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
> I & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & E & I \\
> 0 & I & -E
> \end{bmatrix}$$ Determine $\left( 4 A^{-1} - A^3 \right)^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

I am stuck even at determining the inverse $A^{-1}$. What I normally do is use the Gauss-Jordan elimination or, for $2 \times 2$ matrices, I use the known identity. But I have absolutely no idea what to do with block matrices. I could write the entire block matrix explicitly and work with that, but that would be very painful to do. I am sure there is some elegant way to work with block matrices, which I hope someone would explain to me.

Comment: $E^2=I$  and $A^2$ is diagonal, blocks $I,2I,2I.$  See if you can reproduce that much

Answer (score 1):

$E^2 = I$

$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} I\\&\frac 12 E & \frac 12 I\\&\frac 12 I &-\frac 12 E\end{bmatrix}$

However, it is not usually this easy.

As $(4A^{-1} - A^3) = A^{-1}(4I - A^4),$ I would be inclined to inspect $(4I - A^4)$

$4I - A^4$ gives a diagonal matrix with $3$ in the first $3$ entries and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: the $E,I, I,-E$ lower blocks in the original  reminded me of reflection $ \left( \begin{array}{rr}  \cos t & \sin t \\ \sin t & - \cos t \end{array} \right)$  and does square to double the identity